# Is Mt Hermon located within the biblical boundaries of the Holy Land?

Tags: eretz-yisrael, geography

According to interpreters, Is Mt Hermon located within the biblical boundaries of the Holy Land?

Comment: Isn't Har Snir mentioned in the border our Mt Hermon?

Comment: the Stone edition chumash (page 923) has a map with the borders according to the Kaftor VaFerach and the Tevuos HaAretz and Mt. Hermon is outside both of those (though it is significantly closer to the border as drawn by the T"H.

Comment: @DannySchoemann See Devarim 4:48 and its surrounding verses. It says that Moshe and the army conquered extensive land belonging to the Emori on the east side of the Jordan which includes Hermon. As I understand it, all land on the east of the Jordan was not part of Eretz Yisra'el. Can you confirm or deny this assumption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

> "בַּיּוֹם הַהוּא, כָּרַת ה' אֶת-אַבְרָם--בְּרִית לֵאמֹר: לְזַרְעֲךָ, נָתַתִּי אֶת-הָאָרֶץ הַזֹּאת, **מִנְּהַר מִצְרַיִם**, עַד-**הַנָּהָר הַגָּדֹל נְהַר-פְּרָת**. אֶת-הַקֵּינִי, וְאֶת-הַקְּנִזִּי, וְאֵת, הַקַּדְמֹנִי. וְאֶת-הַחִתִּי וְאֶת-הַפְּרִזִּי, וְאֶת-הָרְפָאִים. וְאֶת-הָאֱמֹרִי, וְאֶת-הַכְּנַעֲנִי, וְאֶת-הַגִּרְגָּשִׁי, וְאֶת-הַיְבוּסִי."

This says from the Nile to the Euphrates. Here's a map I have found, which pretty much sums it up. According to the map, it doesn't pass through.

[image: Source: https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/קובץ:Map_Land_of_Israel.jpg]

Source: [https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/קובץ:Map_Land_of_Israel.jpg](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%91%D7%A5:Map_Land_of_Israel.jpg)

Comment: נהר מצרים isn't the Nile

Comment: It is. The only river in Egypt

Comment: Your map doesn't agree with you. It marks the River of Egypt far from the Nile.

Comment: FWIW, currently, נהר מצרים is part of Egypt or just on the Southern border of Gaza. Regardless, a country can have more than one river. I can't say why this particular one is called "River of Egypt", but geographically, this is not the Nile.

Comment: I accepted the map, thank you, though I think the verse you brought is completely unnecessary it adds nothing to the answer.

Comment: @AlBerko Thanks, but it told me when uploading that the picture have to not be mandatory, but more like an explanation to the TEXT. So I have to include the verses.

Comment: nahar means a valley where rain gathers in the rainy season, not necessarily a river. wadi al arish is the accepted valley that fits nehar mitzrayim and is the border of Israel

Comment: See my comment below the question and the verses that I refer to. It seems to confirm your conclusion.

Comment: Where in the map is "הַנָּהָר הַגָּדֹל נְהַר-פְּרָת" (mentioned in the verse you quote)?

Comment: "[Map showing one interpretation of the borders of the Promised Land, based on God's promise to Abraham (Genesis 15)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promised_Land#/media/File:Greater_Israel_map.jpg)" (from Wikipedia).